# Visual Studio Extensibility, How do you enumerate the projects in a solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Just trying to get up to speed with the SDK...

So, I've created my own tool window....

Now I want to iterate through the existing projects in the currently loaded solution and  display their names in the tool window....

but not quite sure what the best way to enumerate the projects?  any clues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this [code by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/8d2b8fdbb6f2ba1c83f403eefab49cad3710b650/Code_Sweep/C%23/VsPackage/ProjectUtilities.cs#L129-L150):

```
    static public IEnumerable<IVsProject> LoadedProjects
    {
        get
        {
            var solution = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
            if (solution == null)
            {
                Debug.Fail("Failed to get SVsSolution service.");
                yield break;
            }

            IEnumHierarchies enumerator = null;
            Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
            solution.GetProjectEnum((uint)__VSENUMPROJFLAGS.EPF_LOADEDINSOLUTION, ref guid, out enumerator);
            IVsHierarchy[] hierarchy = new IVsHierarchy[1] { null };
            uint fetched = 0;
            for (enumerator.Reset(); enumerator.Next(1, hierarchy, out fetched) == VSConstants.S_OK && fetched == 1; /*nothing*/)
            {
                yield return (IVsProject)hierarchy[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note about the provided Microsoft code link, which is now broken

Comment: Changed to Github link.