# How to get an IVsProject's full path, name?

Tags: visual-studio, path, project, visual-studio-addins

Thanks to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304361/visual-studio-extensibility-how-do-you-enumerate-the-projects-in-a-solution), I can enumerate between the projects in my editor.
Now, I would like to get more information about the IVsProject I got, but [the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsproject_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not really point me to any solution.
How should I do to get the project's name (and full path) ? Also, is there an online resource more detailed/easier to explore than MSDN reference, about the Visual Studio SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BSTR* fileName;
HRESULT hr=pvsProject->GetMkDocument(VSITEMID_ROOT,&fileName);
```